# How do I get my system preferences to show up?

Tags: macos, system-settings

[image]

How do I make my system preferences show up again?  I tried logging in as another account on the same system:

[image]

Comment: ls -la /System/Library/PreferencePanes shows all my .prefPane files (approximately 30 of them).

Comment: Probably obvious; but, you tried to select "Show All Preferences" at the top of the View menu, right?

Comment: Very strange question, I suggest you repair disk and permissions first

Comment: Tried show all prefs and cmd+L.  Nothing.  Have already done a repair disk and permissions (by restarting in the recovery partition.

Comment: did you try to log in as different user?

Comment: If you select a pane from the drop down menu, does that portion of the window render properly? Also, can you open the Console app and see if there are messages that happen when you open or close the system prefs. Since the "all logs" portion can be busy, try opening and closing it several times. Can we presume you rebooted the OS and this happens immediately on the first log in?

Comment: I was wondering if the computer might have been "managed"... but, I just tried to setup an iMac to disable all the preference panes that way, and instead of hiding them, they are all visible (just grayed-out, and disabled).  I don't think this would have changed between 10.9 and 10.10 though.

Comment: I am guessing that there is an .xml somewhere that has a list of the prefpanes.  My guess is it is gone.  This would explain why all the prefpanes work, and are available in the drop down list, but not the sys pref window.

Answer (score 1):

- close system preferences
- go to your home directory and then Library then PreferencePanes. (remove ~/Library/PreferencePanes/*) remove anything in there (to you
  desktop in case you want to sort through them later)
- launch system preferences and see if it acts better.

if not, then go to /Library then PreferencePanes and remove anything there.  (remove /Library/PreferencePanes/*)

if it's a wonky pref pane, this should fix it, with only the system ones remaining.

Comment: any references to your "remove all" suggestion?

Comment: I do not recommend to remove everything from /Library/PreferencePanes/ but, you could relocate them somewhere "safe" like a Desktop or someplace; and, then put them back one at a time to isolate the "bad" one.  Note that this is "/Library/PreferencePanes" and NOT "/System/Library/PreferencePanes", where the standard ones are all stored.

Comment: Already did this dance... no joy.